# What is wrong in the following code?

Tags: tables, errors

I get this error message on the penultimate line (closing brace) of the following table: **Missing $ inserted . }** However, the file compiles and the PDF displays correctly. Nevertheless, the presence of these alarming messages is annoying.

**This is a MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo,array}
\pdfoutput=1

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \extrarowheight = -0.5ex
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.3}
    \boxed{
        \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$\hspace{15pt}}*{6}{>$c<$}}
            
            $ \boxed{\Delta_0  = 33} $&\rightarrow&1&-4&6&-4&1\\
            
            \boxed{\Delta_1 = -3}&\rightarrow&-1&3&-3&1& \vdots \\
            
            \boxed{\Delta_2 = -10}&\rightarrow&1&-2&1&\vdots & \vdots \\
            
            \boxed{\Delta_3 = 12}&\rightarrow&-1&1&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
            
            \boxed{\Delta_4  = 24}&\rightarrow&1&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
            
            && \downarrow &\downarrow &\downarrow &\downarrow &\downarrow\\
            
            &&\boxed{\textbf{38}} &\boxed{\textbf{-109}} &\boxed{\textbf{197}} &\boxed{\textbf{-135}} &\boxed{\textbf{33}}\\
            
            && $ x^4 $ & $ x^3 $ & $ x^2 $ & $ x^1 $ & $ x^0 $
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just posting a fragment  makes it harder for anyone to debug for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `tabular` so columns are text not math so you need `$\rightarrow$` or  math column such as `>{$}c<{$}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\extrarowheight = -0.5ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.3}
\boxed{%
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$\hspace{15pt}}*{6}{>$c<$}}
        
        \boxed{\Delta_0  = 33}&\rightarrow&1&-4&6&-4&1\\
        
         \boxed{\Delta_1 = -3}&\rightarrow&-1&3&-3&1& \vdots \\
        
         \boxed{\Delta_2 = -10}&\rightarrow&1&-2&1&\vdots & \vdots \\
        
         \boxed{\Delta_3 = 12}&\rightarrow&-1&1&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
        
        \boxed{\Delta_4  = 24}&\rightarrow&1&\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
        
        && \downarrow &\downarrow &\downarrow &\downarrow &\downarrow\\
        
        &&\boxed{\textbf{38}} &\boxed{\textbf{-109}} &\boxed{\textbf{197}} &\boxed{\textbf{-135}} &\boxed{\textbf{33}}\\
        
        &&  x^4  &  x^3  &  x^2  &  x^1  &  x^0 
    \end{tabular}%
    } % In this line I get this error message: "Missing  inserted .}"
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David, but the error persists...

Comment: @EternoSirvientedeDios the document in this answer runs without error

Comment: Thanks again David. Yes, you are right, your code does not give an error. I don't know why it was, I had limited myself to copying what seemed to me to be the difference between your code and mine, that is, adding {>$c<$}, but that way I kept getting the same error. However, copying your code in its entirety solved the problem. Surely something was missing...

Comment: @EternoSirvientedeDios I removed some `$` from the last row as I had made the columns automatically math

Comment: Oh!, I see... Best regards, David.